# Tkinter Grid Alignment Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm pretty new with tkinter and I can't figure why the q is not aligned near the Entry.

```
# String
self.user_p = StringVar()
self.user_q = StringVar()
self.user_r = StringVar()
self.user_result = StringVar()

# Label
self.description = Label(self.root, text="!p v (q ^ r)")
self.pLabel = Label(self.root, text="p")
self.qLabel = Label(self.root, text="q")
self.rLabel = Label(self.root, text="r")
self.resultLabel = Label(self.root, text="Result")

# Entry
self.p = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.user_p, width = 10)
self.q = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.user_q, width = 10)
self.r = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.user_r, width = 10)
self.result = Entry(self.root, bg = "white", state=DISABLED, text = "")

# Grid
  # Labels
self.description.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = N)
self.pLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.qLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.rLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = E)

  # Entry
self.p.grid(row=1, column=1)
self.q.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
self.r.grid(row=1, column=5)
```

(with or without the sticky it's still the same)

Here's a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/755kq.jpg

The first part in the picture is what I'm getting right now. And the second part is what I want it to look like

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and augment your code to an mcve.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to temporarily give widgets a distinctive background color so you can see how much space a widget is taking up. I suggest trying `self.pLabel.configure(background="red"` to see if that provides you with any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. I have taken the liberty to attach an example of a test code (see below). Please remember to do that in your post as mine can be different to yours. I did not encounter the issue you described. See attached picture. I am using python3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

One other thing, you can be more explicit by adding the option `justify=RIGHT` in your label widget commands to alight the label text to right.

[image: result]

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='pink')

        # String
        self.user_p = StringVar()
        self.user_q = StringVar()
        self.user_r = StringVar()
        self.user_result = StringVar()

        # Label
        self.description = Label(self, text="!p v (q ^ r)")
        self.pLabel = Label(self, text="p")
        self.qLabel = Label(self, text="q")
        self.rLabel = Label(self, text="r")
        self.resultLabel = Label(self, text="Result")

        # Entry
        self.p=Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_p, width=10)
        self.q=Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_q, width=10)
        self.r=Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_r, width=10)
        self.result=Entry(self, bg="white", state=DISABLED, text="")

        # Grid
          # Labels
        self.description.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N)
        self.pLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.qLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)
        self.rLabel.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=E)

          # Entry
        self.p.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.q.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.r.grid(row=1, column=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry("300x50")
    app=App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```